# how to handle an exception when I set dependencies in the app.xaml.cs file?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application and I declare some dependencies. One of them, is this:

```
services.AddSingleton<CanalGrpc>(miServiceProvider =>
{
    string miStrDireccionServidor = GetDireccionServidor(miServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguracionServicio>());
    int miIntPuertoServidor = 1;

    return new CanalGrpc(miStrDireccionServidor, miIntPuertoServidor);
});
```

Here I use the method GetDireccionServidor to know which address should to use the GrpcChannel.

This method could throw and exception, if I can't ping to the expected address, so it means the server is not available .

The method is this:

```
private string GetDireccionServidor()
{
    try
    {
        Ping miPing = new Ping();
        PingOptions misOpcionesPing = new PingOptions();
        misOpcionesPing.DontFragment = true;
        PingReply miRespuestoPing = miPing.Send("1.1.1.1", 500);

        if (miRespuestoPing.Status == IPStatus.Success) return "1.1.1.1";


        miRespuestoPing = miPing.Send("2.2.2.2", 500);

        if (miRespuestoPing.Status == IPStatus.Success) return "2.2.2.2";


        miRespuestoPing = miPing.Send("3.3.3.3", 500);

        if (miRespuestoPing.Status == IPStatus.Success) return "3.3.3.3";

        return string.Empty;
    }
    catch
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("No se ha podido conectar con el servidor.");
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I can't ping any of the addresses, the application closes without any message because the exception is thrown in the initilization of the application.

How could I handle the exception and show a window telling the problem?

Or perhaps I should use this method in the initialization, but in this case, I don't know how to define the depedency for GrpChannel.

Thanks so much.

Comment: There is a message, its just that Win10 made it hard to see.  Find it back in the Windows Application event log.  This does make implementing an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event rather important.  If the app is supposed to keep running then just do so in code by testing for a String.Empty return.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the `CanalGrpc` object inside a `try`/`catch` block when you start the app and then register the already constructed object directly into the container, e.g.:

```
try
{
    string miStrDireccionServidor = GetDireccionServidor(service);
    int miIntPuertoServidor = 1;

    services.AddSingleton(new CanalGrpc(miStrDireccionServidor, miIntPuertoServidor));

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //initialization failed...alert the user here
}
```